# Finding the minimum of a function over an interval

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, built-in

Upon request by Martin here is the basic problem. There is a function M(x) which is supposed to be minimized over the interval [lb, ub].

```
M = @(x) (a_1 * x + b_1) * (log((a_1 * x + b_1)/P_1) + X_u)...
    + (a_2 * x + b_2) * (log((a_2 * x + b_2)/P_2) + X_m)...
    + x * (log(x / P_3) + X_d);
lb = max(0, -b_1 / a_1);
ub = -b_2 / a_2;
```

where the inputs are:

```
P_1 = 0.6;   
P_2 = 0.2;
P_3 = 0.2; 
a_1 = 0.7071;
a_2 = -1.7071;
b_1 = 0.0245;
b_2 = 0.9755;
X_u = 44;
X_m = 2.9949;
X_d = 0;
```

The other option would be to solve for the root of the equation m_dash:

```
m_dash = @(x) log(((a_1 .* x + b_1).^a_1) .* ((a_2 .* x + b_2).^a_2) .* x)...
    - log((P_1.^a_1) .* (P_2.^a_2) .* P_3) + a_1 .* X_u + a_2 .* X_m + X_d;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a lot of code for finding a zero... Is there any way you can reduce the amount of code to explicitly show the problem?

Comment: Dear Martin, the overall problem is to minimize the function M: '@(x) (a_1 * x + b_1) * (ln((a_1 * x + b_1)/P_1) + X_u)...
    + (a_2 * x + b_2) * (ln((a_2 * x + b_2)/P_2) + X_m)...
    + x * (ln(x / P_3) + X_d);' where the option of finding the zero M' seemed like the most logical one for me in the first place as the uniqueness of the solution has already been proven. But finding this specific zero by using M' turned out a lot more difficult than I initially thought it to be.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! As a hint, you are much more likely to get answers when you throw out the other code and reduce your question to a minimal, working example MWE. (You would need to define `M`, `a_1`, `a_2`, ... for your problem to be a good MWE.) Many people on stackoverflow don't read questions that have lots of code in them.

Comment: Also, when you do the algebra, finding the minimum of your function with respect to x reduces to finding the zero of a quadratic polynomial - is there a reason you are not looking for the algebraic solution?

Comment: Your short example is not valid Matlab – I assume you mean `log` for `ln`. Also, as @MartinJ.H. suggests, please provide numeric values for all of your parameters (or at least indicate assumptions, relationships, and bounds for them).

Comment: Hi Martin and horchler I just added the numeric values, I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: Have you tried plotting your function `M` over your domain. For the parameters given it does not cross zero, i.e., it does not have a root. ... Now I see that you changed the title and nature of your question. So now you're interested in a minimum, not a zero? Just use `fminbnd`.

Comment: There are basically two options to solve this, either solve it for the minimum of M or find the root of a the equality provided before. Let me just put the other option also back into the general outline of the question.

Comment: Your `m_dash` has a typo – possibly missing a parenthesis at the end? and what's with `+ -`?

Comment: I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to minimize a function over a certain interval, you can use the [`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html) function from the Optimization Toolbox. If you don't have that toolbox installed, you can either try a [free alternative](https://github.com/rdeits/MatlabOptimizationTools/blob/master/fminsearchbnd.m), or instead coerce the built-in function [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) to only return results from the interval:

```
rlv = 1e12; % ridiculously large value
M_hacked= @(x) rlv*((x < lb) + (x > ub))  + M(x);
x_min = fminsearch(M_hacked, (lb + ub)/2)
```

I introduced a new function, `M_hacked`, which returns ridiculously large values for `x` outside of the interval.

This is not be the most elegant solution, but it should do for your problem.

Comment: I just tried your answer out and and its answer is by 0.0006 more accurate than fminbnd. Even though both work. Thank you very much!